# How to undo Revert and save files (SmartGit)

Tags: git, revert, smartgit

I seem to be breaking a project I have been working on for 2 months. I am using SmartGit:
At first I wanted to commit all the files, but the size turned out to be large and I did Revert thinking that it would just undo the commit, but this deleted all local files.

[image]

How can I undo the deletion and save the files?
[image]

Comment: You should be able to revert the revert commit - it's a commit like any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SmartGit, just invoke Local|Undo Last Commit; this will put your changes back to the Index. Now you may revert them partially or all together using Local|Discard - **it helped to revert the changes.**